# AppSettingsSection does not exist

Tags: c#

I have been reading the documentation on [AppSettings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) and found the code where the very first line they use `AppSettingsSection appSettings =config.AppSettings as AppSettingsSection;`

So I went to the [AppSettingsSection page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection(v=vs.110).aspx) in the documentation.

My problem is that even though it is in the documentation, this "AppSettingsSection" does not exist in System.Configuration when I try to put the code in visual studio 2017.

Can someone point to me what I am overlooking to make this code compile?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add "System.Configuration.dll" to the Project references?

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Thanks. That was very useful. Now almost everything is corrected except that `config` (used in the example) is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection(v=vs.110).aspx. 
It works with Visual Studio 2017 when you add System.Configuration.dll to the Project references like Daniel W. mentioned.